# VS Code auto submit changes doesn't work for 1 file

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

The .js file for a lightning web component won't deploy to my org when I save the file in VS Code, but deploys fine if I right click in the file explorer and select Deploy Source to Org. The output window shows that when auto save is used the filename has a capital at the start, but when I submit through file explorer the file is all lower case (as it should be for this file).

I've searched my project folder and found a reference to the uppercase filename in custom-components.json, so I changed the name there to be all lower case, however I still get the issue. It's not a massive problem, it's just a pain having to manually deploy the file every time I save...

Has anyone seen this issue before? I'm hoping there's just a cache somewhere I don't know about/can't find. Thanks!